# What if I do not finish my weekly challenge

Tags: clash-of-clans

Every week we get 6 challenges; and 3 daily challenges..

What if I couldn't finish suppose a weekly challenge. Now, when a new week starts and 6 new challenges are launched.. will this my un-finished challenge go away.. or  it will still be active and i can finish it in next week.

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed now myself.. I had one challenge not finished; and now when 6 new weekly challenges were launched.. now I have 7 challenges pending.. So, its ok you can be relaxed while finishing weekly challenges.. take your time